# AngularJS | Build a path from folders

Tags: angularjs

I am currently browsing folders recursively and I want to "build" the path of my folders.

Now I can create the path like this: `folder1/folder2/folder3` with a String variable that I update like this:

```
path += nameOfFolder + "/";
```

but when I go back to `folder2` my path is like: `folder1/folder2/folder3/folder2`.

I just want to remove the last object of my list and not adding it.

Are there something in AngularJS to do automatically all this system, or do I have to make that manually?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you doing, but angularjs could use routing with `ngRoute` or `ui.router`. As a hack, you can try splitting the string and checking for the previous folder: `a = "folder1/folder2/folder3"`, `b = a.split("/")`, `b[b.length-2] == "folder2"`

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, but i have another problem now : 

I want to detect when the user is going back to a folder so that i can remove the last object of the list

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know how are you using folders in AngularJS. But assuming you already have a way for navigating between them, I suggest using a **stack** to keep the track of which folders you have visited. A stack is just an array that works on a principal *Last-in-First-out*. I made this small simulation for pagination:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.stack = [];
  $scope.path = "/";
  $scope.go_to = function(name) {
    if (!name || (name == $scope.stack[$scope.stack.length - 1])) {
      return;
    }
    var index = $scope.stack.indexOf(name)
    if (index >= 0) { // found such folder
      $scope.stack = $scope.stack.slice(0, index + 1);
    } else {
      $scope.stack.push(name);
    }
    $scope.path = "/" + $scope.stack.join("/");
  }
  $scope.go_back = function() {
    $scope.stack.pop();
    $scope.path = "/" + $scope.stack.join("/");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <h3>Folders simulation</h3>

  Stack: <code>{{stack}}</code>
  <br> 
  Path: <code>{{path}}</code>
  <hr>
  <button ng-click="go_to(folder_name)">Go to:</button> <input type="text" ng-model="folder_name" /><br>
  <button ng-click="go_back()">Go back</button>

</div>
```