# "Go Back" button for folders and sub-folders in the single URL web application

Tags: java, html, css, angularjs

I am developing **single URL web application**, in that URL page i am going to show folders and sub-folder like **how we have in windows.**

Now i want to develop "Go Back" functionality, If i click on the "Go Back" *i want show parent folder of the current folder and vice versa.*

**URL will not change.It remains same.**

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/50464962/8495123

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I totally understand the "go to parent folder" and how my answer will help but I have developed a C++ program to make a series of 'favorites' html pages from my Firefox bookmarks.   And each page has a GO BACK button to go to the previous page.   In my case the previous page is the parent in the tree.

But this code is simply a button the does nothing more than the back button on your browser.

```
 <input type="button" value="Go Back" onClick="history.go(-1)">
```

But it works for my application.

Comment: I have already tried that. In that case it is changing the URL means it is going to previous URL page but if you see my question "URL remains same "